# Zhang Suen thinning too extreme -- Python implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing

I am trying to thin an image of a fingerprint.
Below you can see the result and the input superposed:

[image]

As, you can see, lots of lines are broken. Is my implementaiton of the algoritm the problem ? (sorry for the french variable names):

This outputs 1 if the pixel is "black enough"

```
def couleur (valeur):
    if valeur > 200:
        couleur = 0
    else:
        couleur = 1
    return couleur
```

This turns an image into a matrix:

```
def image_vers_matrice (chemin):
    matrice = []
    image = Image.open(chemin)
    pixels = image.load()
    largeur, hauteur = image.size
    for i in range(hauteur):
        matrice.append([])
        for j in range(largeur):
            matrice[-1].append(couleur(pixels[j, i][0]))
    return matrice
```

This turns a matrix into an image:

```
def matrice_vers_image (matrice):
    image = Image.new('RGB', (len(matrice[0]), len(matrice)), 'white')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    for i in range(len(matrice)):
        for j in range(len(matrice[0])):
            if(matrice[i][j] == 1):
                draw.point([(j, i)], fill=0)
    return image
```

This is used in the algorithm (number of transitions from white to black around a point):

```
def nombre_transitions (image, i, j):
    transitions = 0
    if image[i - 1][j] == 0 and image[i - 1][j + 1] == 1:
        transitions += 1
    if image[i - 1][j + 1] == 0 and image[i][j + 1] == 1:
        transitions += 1
    if image[i + 1][j + 1] == 0 and image[i + 1][j] == 1:
        transitions += 1
    if image[i + 1][j] == 0 and image[i + 1][j - 1] == 1:
        transitions += 1
    if image[i + 1][j - 1] == 0 and image[i][j - 1] == 1:
        transitions += 1
    if image[i][j - 1] == 0 and image[i - 1][j - 1] == 1:
        transitions += 1
    if image[i - 1][j - 1] == 0 and image[i - 1][j] == 1:
        transitions += 1
    return transitions
```

Also used in the algorithm (number of neighbours):

```
def nombre_voisins_8 (image, i, j):
    #on suppose que le point est noir et n'est pas sur un bord
    voisins = 0
    for k in range(i - 1, i + 2):
        for l in range(j - 1, j + 2):
            voisins += image[k][l]
    return voisins - 1
```

The actual thing:

```
def zhang_suen (argument_image):
    image = []
    for i in range(len(argument_image)):
        image.append([x for x in argument_image[i]])
    continuer = True
    while continuer:
        continuer = False
        a_supprimer = []
        for i in range(1, len(image) - 1):
            for j in range(1, len(image[0]) - 1):
                condition = True
                condition = condition and image[i][j] == 1
                condition = condition and 2 <= nombre_voisins_8(image, i, j) <= 6
                condition = condition and nombre_transitions(image, i, j) == 1
                condition = condition and (image[i - 1][j] == 0 or image[i][j + 1] == 0 or image[i + 1][j] == 0)
                condition = condition and (image[i][j - 1] == 0 or image[i][j + 1] == 0 or image[i + 1][j] == 0)
                if condition:
                    a_supprimer.append((i, j))
                    continuer = True
        for x in a_supprimer:
            i, j = x
            image[i][j] = 0
        for i in range(1, len(image) - 1):
            for j in range(1, len(image[0]) - 1):
                condition = True
                condition = condition and image[i][j] == 1
                condition = condition and 2 <= nombre_voisins_8(image, i, j) <= 6
                condition = condition and nombre_transitions(image, i, j) == 1
                condition = condition and (image[i - 1][j] == 0 or image[i][j + 1] == 0 or image[i][j - 1] == 0)
                condition = condition and (image[i][j - 1] == 0 or image[i - 1][j] == 0 or image[i + 1][j] == 0)
                if condition:
                    a_supprimer.append((i, j))
                    continuer = True
        for x in a_supprimer:
            i, j = x
            image[i][j] = 0
        a_supprimer = []
    return image
```

This saves the thinned image (the green one in the image above)

```
matrice_vers_image(zhang_suen(image_vers_matrice('test2.jpg'))).save('test3.png')
```

Comment: I based my implementation on this article (link currently broken, hope it will be fixed soon): https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zhang-Suen_thinning_algorithm

Comment: This is the Google Cache version: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FMOzn6oisrUJ:https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zhang-Suen_thinning_algorithm+&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr&client=ubuntu

Comment: This is interesting but for a early european morning quite some problem ;-) Skimming over the enlarged image overlay, I have the impression,that the defects occur more in regions, where the thick lines either are thin and curved, or thick lines are more like torqued rectangular blocks where the algorithm (or your cartesian coordinate logics) might have problems. Is the underlying greyish input a single level grey image or are there "shades of grey"?

Comment: You are right, certain areas are more impacted than others. The original image is black in white, but the borders contain greyish variations. That is why I made the function `couleur` that defines a threshold. The black part of the image above is result of turning the original image to a matrix, and then back to an image, thus keeping only #000 black and #FFF white. So the lines aren't broken before the algorithm begins

Comment: I remember a good check of such an explicitly cartesian  decomposed algorithm is to verify identity of the result under simple and lossless invariant transformations of the base system in your case I would simply make two runs or so in addition to that one and compare all retransformed results with each other: Rotate input by 90 degree, mirror input say at right border. Than any asymmetries in your indexing logic should either become obvious or excluded. Subsequently I would check thinning core algo in detail.

Comment: Do you respect the condition "on suppose que le point est noir " ?

Comment: Yves Daoust it does not matter because the dot being black is part of the condition

Comment: Dilettant so I should rotate the input and see if the same regions fail ?

Comment: @Ghuizing If you want people to be notifiied of your comments, start them with `@username`.